# git-latexdiff and relative imports on linux

Tags: graphics, png, latexdiff

I have a paper which is basically structured in a directory this way:

```
mypaper/
    main.tex
    sections/
        intro.tex
        methods.tex
        conclusions.tex
    img/
        img1.png
        img2.png
```

My main looks essentially like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{...}
...

\graphicspath{{./img/}}

...

\begin{document}
\input{sections/intro}
....
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{fig1.png}
\end{figure}
....

\end{document}
```

pdflatex compiles like a charm, while latexdiff (I am using git-latexdiff, but I guess it doesn't change much) gives me the following error:

```
Package pdftex.def Error: File `img/fig1.png' not found.
```

I know I could get rid of this error if I make latexdiff ignore figures or if I set draft in documentclass options, but I want to get pictures in my latexdiff.
How do I fix that?

Comment: I do believe it is a problem with git-latexdiff rather than latexdiff. latexdiff should not interfere with the graphicspath but git-latexdiff might create temporary directory structure not conforming to expectations (I don't know git-latexdiff, though). An alternative could be latexdiff-vc (see manuals) with --git and --flatten option?

Comment: Got the same problem, and `--whole-tree` didn't help in my case. Most of the images were fine, but one image was not, just like you've described. Turned out, that file was not tracked, and this seems to be what was causing the problem for `git-latexdiff`, and so just staging that file resolved the issue. Another file I had this problem with was matching one of the blacklisted patterns in `.gitignore`, so that's one more thing to check. Finally, I believe these "problems" aren't specific to GNU/Linux systems, they likely can appear on Mac OS and Windows as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `--whole-tree` option in `git-latexdiff` is what you're looking for.

```
git-latexdiff --whole-tree HEAD~1
```

By default `git-latexdiff` only copies the part of the repository tree that contains the `--main` file to the temporary folder. With the `--whole-tree` option it will copy the whole tree including graphics files in other directories.